# To solve ambiguity of overloaded function without either adding typecasting or remove the overloaded functions

Tags: c++, casting, ambiguity

I made a class `Dummy`, which is just a wrapper of primitive type `double`. The purpose of the class is to test potential problems before I introduce another class that substitutes the `double` class.

Dummy.h:

```
class Dummy{
private:
    double content;
public:
    Dummy(double _content) :content{ _content } {};
    operator long int()  {return (long int)content;};
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    Dummy a = Dummy(1.1);
    double aa = fabs(a);
}
```

It reports:

```
<source>:17:27: error: call of overloaded 'fabs(Dummy&)' is ambiguous 
   17 |     std::cout << std::fabs(foo);
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~ In file included from /usr/include/features.h:461,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:586,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/cmath:41,
                 from <source>:1: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:162:1: note: candidate:
'double fabs(double)'
  162 | __MATHCALLX (fabs,, (_Mdouble_ __x),
(__const__));
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from <source>:1: /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/cmath:241:3:
note: candidate: 'constexpr float std::fabs(float)'
  241 |  
fabs(float __x)
      |   ^~~~ /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/cmath:245:3:
note: candidate: 'constexpr long double std::fabs(long double)'
  245 |   fabs(long double __x)
```

If I add a type conversion operator:

```
operator double(){
    return content;
}
```

It somehow only works under Visual Studio, not g++ 9.3.0, which is my target compiler.

During the compiling with g++ 9.3.0, the following errors are reported:

[image: Error Message from g++]

I have read the information [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-the-operators-that-can-be-and-cannot-be-overloaded-in-cpp/), unfortunately I can't remove the overloaded functions in this case. Neither can I add typecasting, because it doesn't make sense for my purpose.

I also check [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.mem), but I am not so familiar with templates. Hence my question is:

Can I eliminate the ambiguity of overloaded function within the class, without adding typecasting, or removing the overloaded functions?

Comment: Please don't include images of text. Copy-paste the text with formatting into your question. Also, have a look at how to make a [mre]. Include the code that produces the error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the error in action. Why, exactly, can't you use a typecast to specify the overload you want to call?

Comment: @super Directly pasted imformation looks chaotic.

Comment: Here is a minimal example showing how implicit type conversion should work: https://godbolt.org/z/sa1qPP7fj  -- it's unclear from your question exactly what you're doing differently, because you've omitted all useful detail.  I suggest you build up your minimal example to demonstrate the issue, using my example as a starter.  Then [edit that code into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71025854/edit).  Only then can there be a conversation about the actual problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the purpose of the dummy class is to be substituted by another class, this class is to replace the primitive double type, therefore it doesn't make sense to cast it back to double.

Comment: @paddy It's done.

Comment: “It doesn’t make sense to cast it to double” then it will match zero overloads to the function you’re calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dummy` class you have shown is only convertible to `long int`, but `fabs()` does not accept `long int`, it accepts either `float`, `double`, or `long double`.  Since `long int` is implicitly convertible to `float` and `double`, the call was ambiguous until you added the `double` conversion operator.

If you don't want to do that, then you have to be explicit about which overload of `fabs()` you want to call.  Either by:

- casting the result of the `Dummy` conversion:

  ```
  double aa = fabs(static_cast<double>(a));
  ```
- assigning/casting `fabs()` to a function pointer of the desired signature:

  ```
  double (*fabs_ptr)(double) = fabs;
  fabs_ptr(a);
  ```

  ```
  using fabs_ptr = double (*)(double);
  static_cast<fabs_ptr>(fabs)(a);
  ```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/zehFQL)

Comment: I used another solution, but thank you anyway!